# ActionListener to buttons , seems like JOptionPane interfere

Tags: java, actionlistener, joptionpane

I have this sample. It is a simple program.
Press Me button calls a JOptionPane.
Exit Button calls `System.exit`.
The problem is that button OK of `JOptionPane` seem to call "else" (alongside buttonExt) and exits the program.
How can I manipulate a `JOptionPane` button?

```
package javatests;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author fotis
 */
public class AreaCalculation extends JFrame 
implements ActionListener {

    private JButton button;
    private JButton exitBtn;

public static void main(String[] args){
    AreaCalculation frame=new AreaCalculation();
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.createGUI();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}    
     public void createGUI(){
      FlowLayout flow=new FlowLayout();  
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      Container window=getContentPane();
      window.setLayout(flow);
      button=new JButton("Press me");
      window.add(button);
      button.addActionListener(this);
      exitBtn=new JButton("Exit");
      window.add(exitBtn);
      exitBtn.addActionListener(this);
    }           

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int area,length,width;
        length = 20;
        width =10;
        area= length*width;
        if(e.getSource()==button){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Area is : " + area); 
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==exitBtn);
        {System.exit(0);}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     else if(e.getSource()==exitBtn);
```

**That trainling ; is your `else`, `{System.exit(0);}` is a block on it's own.**

Correctly formatted this would equal:

```
else if(e.getSource()==exitBtn) {
   ;
}

{
   System.exit(0);}
}
```

Correct code:

```
else if(e.getSource()==exitBtn) {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Oh.I am terrible sorry for the oversight.There are these times that you really have to quit writing and take a walk.Anywayz thank you for your time Jan.

Comment: You don't want to know how many times that happend to me before my eyes adjusted to *seeing* such stuff ;-)